# porque no funciona con el let?

Tags: xquery

Estoy usando Xbase de programa la idea es mostrar el dinero que ganaria una profesora "laura" que no conocemos su apellido si toda las plazas de su baile se completan

```
for $dato in doc("bailes") //baile
where starts-with($dato/profesor,"Laura")
return <sala>{sum(($dato/plazas)*data($dato/precio))}</sala>
```

hasta hay lo entiendo pero porque no vale un let puesto que yo quiero una suma y no tengo porque saber que solo tiene un baile no debería valer también un let?

Comment: Segun mi opinion, te aviso que no se mucho el problema es porque tiene un solo baile tal y como comentas, si tuviera mas deberia funcionar

Comment: Haría falta un ejemplo mínimo y reproducible para saber porqué no está resultando la expresión `xquery`. El espacio entre //baile y doc("bailes") es un defecto de escribirlo en la pregunta o lo tienes así realmente?